# Why is the memory allocated from componentsSeparatedByString never being allocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a iOS app which does alot of calculation and is using standard ARC for memory management. After I run it for a few minutes it crashes due to being out out memory. I checked with Instruments and most of the memory is being eaten up by allocations from a call to NSString's commentsSeparatedByString.

I tried running it in a autorelease pool but that didn't help much. Since there are no references to that string outside of my function, I'm confused why the memory isn't being automatically deallocated. I also have another function which is having the same problem with commentsSeparatedByString.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) processWorkWithExtraData:(NSData *) extraData
{
@autoreleasepool {

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:extraData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *dataArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; // eats up memory like crazy!!!

    NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0;i<[dataArray count];i += 1)
    {
        TestObject *p = [[TestObject alloc] initWithFloat:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]]; 

        [objectArray addObject:p];

    }

    [self processArray: objectArray]; // just performs math computations on the floats in the objects

}
}
```

If anyone can let me know why memory would not be freed here please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, I thought I was using ARC but I wasn't (:

Good thing is this fixes my memory issues.

Bad thing is that it's much slower (50-70% slower).

I guess that's the price one has to pay for the magic that is ARC.

Comment: ARC should not be ANY slower. It does the same work as manual reference counting, except the compiler takes care of it for you. In fact, ARC is usually slightly faster since the LLVM compiler is able to remove unneeded retain/release/autorelease calls. If I were you I would run it through the time profiler in Instruments and see if I could figure out what's taking so long.

Comment: Literally the only thing I changed was the ARC setting, so that clearly has some direct impact. The program involves a mathematically based simulation so it's supposed to be 'slow', though it may be that my object management code isn't optimal (I have thousands of small objects) which may be why the ARC has such a big effect.

Comment: If what you say is true you should post a bug to Apple's bug reporter service and use your app as an example. ARC should not be slower. It would be worth running the non-ARC and ARC versions through the Instruments performance profiler and seeing where the extra time comes from. About the only thing I can think of is different handling of auto-release pools is causing your app to run low on memory and generating "churn" but that seems unlikely. The boundary between low memory churn and crashing is pretty thin.

Comment: iOS does not have paged virtual memory like Unix normal does, so the app shouldn't be ["thrashing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))